# Join tables showing all records for each week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was hoping someone would be able to help me.   I have two tables, one with student names and the other with the the amount of homework each student has done, each week (not a real example).  Only one student has done any work.  I would like to see a table showing all the students and how much work they have done (even if it is null, for each week.

```
CREATE TABLE #NAME (Name VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #NAME VALUES
('John'),('Tom'),('Jack')

CREATE TABLE #TIME (Name VARCHAR(20), Week INT, Year INT, Total INT)

INSERT INTO #TIME VALUES
('John',1,2017,34),('John',2,2017,24),('John',3,2017,65),('John',4,2017,22),('John',5,2017,45)
```

I thought a left outer join would work - but it only references the join between names and not weeks

```
SELECT 
#Name.Name,
#Time.Week,
#Time.Year,
#Time.Total

FROM #NAME LEFT OUTER JOIN #Time ON #NAME.Name = #Time.Name
```

I tried a outer apply - but essentially get the same thing -

```
SELECT 
#Name.Name,
A.Week,
A.Year,
A.Total

FROM #NAME OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM #TIme WHERE #Name.Name = #Time.Name) A
```

The output from the above two queries is shown below - alongside what I am trying to get - repeating for each week, showing all students regardless of whether they have any values associated or not.

[image]

I'd be really appreciative if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get all combinations of `Name`, `Week`, and `Year` and then do a `LEFT JOIN` on `#TIME` to get the desired result:

```
WITH CteNameWeekYear(Name, [Week], [Year]) AS(
    SELECT
        n.*, t.*
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT [Week], [Year]  FROM #TIME
    ) t
    CROSS JOIN #Name n
)
SELECT
    c.Name,
    c.[Week],
    c.[Year],
    t.Total
FROM CteNameWeekYear c
LEFT JOIN #TIME t
    ON c.Name = t.Name
    AND c.[Year] = t.[Year]
    AND c.[Week] = t.[Week]
ORDER BY c.[Year], c.[Week], c.Name;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/616478)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.Week, t.Year
    FROM #TIME t
), cte1 AS (
    SELECT n.Name, cte.Week, cte.Year
    FROM #NAME n
    CROSS JOIN cte
)
SELECT
    n.Name, n.Week, n.Year, t.Total
FROM
    cte1 n
    LEFT JOIN #TIME t ON n.NAME = t.NAME AND n.Week = t.Week AND n.Year = t.Year
```